# Pandas time series decomposition based on leap year

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, decomposition

I have a pandas Time Series (called *df*)  that has one column (with name *data*) that contains data with a daily frequency over a time period of 5 years. The following code produces some random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_index = pd.date_range('01-01-2012', periods=5 * 365 + 2, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.rand(len(df_index))}, index=df_index)
```

I want to perform a simple yearly trend decomposition, where for each day I subtract its value one year ago. Aditionally, I want to attend leap years in the subtraction. Is there any elegant way to do that? My way to do this is to perform differences with 365 and 366 days and assign them to new columns.

```
df['diff_365'] = df['data'].diff(365)
df['diff_366'] = df['data'].diff(366)
```

Afterwards, I apply a function to each row thats selects the right value based on whether the same date from last year is 365 or 366 days ago.

```
def decide(row):
    if (row.name - 59).is_leap_year:
        return row[1]
    else:
        return row[0]

df['yearly_diff'] = df[['diff_365', 'diff_366']].apply(decide, axis=1)
```

**Explanation**: the function *decide* takes as argument a row from the DataFrame consisting of the columns *diff_365* and *diff_366* (along with the DatetimeIndex). The expression *row.name* returns the date of the row and assuming the time series has daily frequency (*freq = 'D'*), 59 days are subtracted which is the number of days from 1st January to 28th February. Based on whether the resulting date is a day from a leap year, the value from the *diff_366* column is returned, otherwise the value from the *diff_365* column.

This took 8 lines and it feels that the subtraction can be performed in one or two lines. I tried to apply a similiar function directly to the *data* column (via *apply* and taking the default argument *axis=0*). But in this case, I cannot take my DatetimeIndex into account. Is there a better to perform the subtraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need to worry about dealing with leap years explicitly. When you construct a `DatetimeIndex`, you can specify `start` and `end` parameters. As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

> Of the four parameters `start`, `end`, `periods`, and `freq`, exactly three
>   must be specified.

Here's an example of how you can restructure your logic:

```
df_index = pd.date_range(start='01-01-2012', end='12-31-2016', freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.rand(len(df_index))}, index=df_index)

df['yearly_diff'] = df['data'] - (df_index - pd.DateOffset(years=1)).map(df['data'].get)
```

**Explanation**

- We construct a `DatetimeIndex` object by supplying `start`, `end` and `freq` arguments.
- Subtract 1 year from your index by subtracting `pd.DateOffset(years=1)`.
- Use `pd.Series.map` to map these 1yr behind dates to `data`.
- Subtract the resulting series from the original `data` series.